# list of Timezones, languages and countries

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to get a list of countries, a list of languages, and a list of timezones. I tried to use the L10NManager but this library gives only one of each. Is there a way of getting these lists and intergrating them in my app?

Answer (score 0):

This cn1lib contains such a list and list of flags to match: https://github.com/codenameone/SMSActivation/

Comment: I checked that and it has a list of countries, their flags and country codes. So, I am still missing a list of timezones and a list of languages

Comment: We don't have those at this time. There's plenty of lists on the internet though.